# Why different count results on consecutive reads?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code that is reading a table to a apache spark DataFrame:

```
val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:host/database").option("dbtable", "tablename").option("user", "username").option("password", "password").load()
```

When I first invoke `df.count()` I get a smaller number than the next time I invoke the same `count` method.

Why this happen?

Doesn't Spark load a snapshot of my table in a DataFrame on my Spark Cluster when I first read that table?

My table on *postgres* keeps being fed and it seems my data frame is reflecting this behavior.

How should I manage to load just a static snapshot my table to spark's DataFrame by the time `read` method was invoked?

Comment: have you tried to check table row count at postgresql side?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram yes, it's exactly the same result I get from count method on spark side. So my spark DataFrame is really reflecting this dynamic behavior from my table on postgres

Comment: I think...may be spark is reading only committed data of postgre sql that why your df.count is varying time to time.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram, yeah, that sounds what is going under the hood here. I thought Spark read everything once and then subsequent calls on the DataFrame would consider that static copy of my table that was load on Spark Cluster. But doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: "How should I manage to load just a static snapshot my table to spark's DataFrame by the time read method was invoked?" - cant you introduce a snapshot id,snapshot_datetime at postgre table level and then read it from spark sql based on these parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Dataset` is `cached` using reliable storage (standard Spark `cache` will give you only weak guarantees) database may be accessed multiple times, each time showing the current state of the database. Since

> table on postgres keeps being fed

seeing different counts is an expected behavior.

Furthermore, if JDBC source is used in a distributed mode (with partitioning column or `predicates`), then each executor thread will use its own transaction. As a result the state of the `Dataset` may not fully consistent.

> How should I manage to load just a static snapshot

Don't use JDBC. You can for example

- [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) data to a file system and load it from there.
- Use replication solution of your choice to create a replica dedicated for analytics and set and pause the replication while use analyze the data.