# Spark: Record count mismatch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am quite confused because I am facing a weird situation.
My spark application reads data from an Oracle database and load it into a dataframe using this instruction:

```
  private val df = spark.read.jdbc(
    url = [the jdbc url],
    table="(" + [the query] + ") qry",
    properties= [the oracle driver]
  )
```

Then, I save in a variable the number of records in this dataframe:

```
val records = df.count()
```

The I create a hive table ([my table]) with the dataframe schema, and I dump the content of the dataframe on it:

```
df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .insertInto([my hive db].[my table])
```

Well, here is where I am lost; When I perform a `select count(*)` to the hive table where the dataframe is being loaded, "sometimes" there are a few records more in hive than in the `records` variable.

Can you think on what could be the source of this mismatch??

---

*Related to the *possible duplicate*, my question is different. I am not counting my dataframe many times with different values. I count the records on my dataframe once. I dump the dataframe into hive, and I count the records in the hive table, and sometimes there are more in hive than in my count.*

---

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: JDBC source can see an arbitrary state of the data. It is not even guaranteed that this state is consistent at any point in time, not to mention across separate action. So what makes you think that the count should be constant? Have you placed the source in read-only mode?

Comment: Thanks @user10465355 for your comment. I would understand what you say if I performed a `select count(*)` to the database using jdbc. However, the count that I am doing is over the dataframe directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why different count results on consecutive reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721033/why-different-count-results-on-consecutive-reads)

Comment: Thanks @user10465355 for the link. Event the question seems similar, is not exactly the same. I am creating a dataframe from an oracle query. And then, I count the records into the dataframe, for instance, it returns `100`. Then, I count the records in Hive, and "sometimes" (most of the times they match) there are, for instance, `102`. How is it possible that if the dataframe has 100 records, and I am inserting it into the hive table, the hive table have `102`!???

Comment: `DataFrame` doesn't store the data. In fact `count` doesn't even fetch the data as such in general case, but a series of ones `1` corresponding to to the current state of the database, __as seen by Spark application at particular moment in time__. Each time you execute action the state might be different.

Comment: I have already resolved the issue using the spark web ui. When you use the count method in a dataframe, it takes the query used to populate the dataframe in a subquery, and then it counts each record one by one, sending a new query to the rdbms data source. Because of this, the number of records between the query used to populate the dataframe and the query used to count can vary.